# When will NSFireDelayedPerform be triggered

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa

I tried to figure out when will the `NSFireDelayedPerform` be triggered and what's the basic rule of this.
But I could not find any documentation or source code mentioning about this.
Can anybody provide a little hint?

Comment: Why do you ask it, do you get that listed in some crash log?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I encountered this too and believe this may be called whenever a selector is to be performed after a specified delay (below it's 2 seconds).

```
[foo performSelector:@selector(f1) withObject:nil afterDelay:2];
```

Below is from the stack trace on the main thread where the app was killed after a delay of 20.060 seconds. Despite the specified 2 second delay, the system took much longer (over 10s) to perform this selector. This implies that the system uses an NSTimer to process the *performSelector* calls with the *afterDelay* parameter. Unfortunately, it seems to perhaps put the call on the event queue of the main thread and then wait for the specified delay (or more):

> 6   Foundation                        0x35bfaa6a __NSFireDelayedPerform
>
> 7   CoreFoundation                    0x3add45dc
> **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 12

Answer (score 0):

I would start here

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH16-SW1

there is no mentioning of `NSFireDelayedPerform` but it makes somehow sense as this is normally seen in the context of `CFRunLoop`.

Also maybe you want to look here:

[Is there any guide for iOS runloop mechanism?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216664/is-there-any-guide-for-ios-runloop-mechanism)

Or actually even more basic:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/MainEventLoop.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually I experienced certain scenario as for the same UI interaction, this "NSFireDelayedPerform" will some times be called but not for the other. Such as for UITableView scroll or selection, if interact really crazy, this "NSFireDelayedPerform" will likely be triggered.